# Download part of a video with curl

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to download a segment of a video using CURL.
When I use 
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RANGE, {TIME-RANGE-IN-BYTES});`
I get a part of the file, but it still holds the original time frame and plays a blackscreen through it all.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible?
Thanks ahead

Comment: I am sensing a video to GIF here.

Comment: Quite the detective you are :) . Why, any better way to come about it?

Comment: Not very experienced with video encoding. I am guessing you'll have to download all and use a specialized video processing library to cut a piece out of it.